# android datepicker 18 year old validation

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using this code to set custom date for datepicker ..
// method to create date picker dialog

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // set default date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // get selected date
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = month;
        mDay = day;

        // show selected date to date button
        dob.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(mYear).append("-")
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mDay).append(" "));
    }
}
```

My scenario is that when ever user set a date the date should verify that user is atleast 18 year old ..otherwise it will show alert user is atleast 18 year old ..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try using the Calendar class.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar userAge = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);
    Calendar minAdultAge = new GregorianCalendar();
    minAdultAge.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
    if (minAdultAge.before(userAge)) {
        SHOW_ERROR_MESSAGE;
    } 
}
```

this should do what you want :)

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 568025136000L);
```